# FindByNameAsync throwing null exception

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

Currently my application that is asp.net core application validates user by userEmail which now needs to be change to validate it by userName. 
I have changed the method to FindByNameAsync from FindByEmailAsync. It works If I enter the email address but if I use a 
n userName it doesn't work. It throws a null exception for response.Result.UserName
Could somebody tell me what the problem could be

```
public async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
        {
            var userName = GetUserName(user);
            return await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
        }

 private string GetUserName(string userName)
        {
            //if (!userNameOrEmail.Contains("@"))
            //    return userNameOrEmail;

            var response = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

            return response.Result != null ? response.Result.UserName : string.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: What is the value for `string userName` and what is the value in the database? If you try `var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("test1@outlook.com");` first to get the user, and then try `var user1 = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);`, will it return expected value ?

Answer (score 0):

You should await asynchronous calls to get results:

```
var response = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
```

Also you will need to decorate GetUserName function with `async`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't block on async tasks. You're in an async method, so there's no reason not to actually await the result:

```
private async Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(string userName)
{
    var response = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    return response?.UserName ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Then:

```
var userName = await GetUserNameAsync(user);
```

Second, this doesn't make any sense anyways, as you *already* have the username. You just need to know whether it exists yet or not. As such, you should really have something like?

```
public async Task<bool> UserNameExistsAsync(string userName)
{
    return await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName) != null;
}
```

Then:

```
if (await UserNameExistsAsync(user))
{
    // do something
}
```

And, actually, it would be *better* to use the context directly here, but that might require an additional dependency:

```
var userNameExists = await _context.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.UserName == user);
```

Regardless, the source of your issue is that when it comes time to call `PasswordSignInAsync`, the value you're passing in for `userName` could be an empty string, which is not a valid value for that param. Wrapping this call in a conditional  would fix the issue, such that you only run it if the user actually exists.

Comment: I tried the method GetUserNameAsync but that returns only null even if parameter username is passed with a valid value